# Python open email client with attachment

Tags: python, email, attachment

I'm trying to open a email-client (eg thunderbird) to send an email with an attachment. I have tried to open the client with `webbrowser.open('mailto:[...]?attachment="path_to_file"')`, but there was no attachment. I also tried to write `file://path_to_file`.
I have searched in the web for a solution, but there I only found tutorials how to send emails with SMTP. Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

I would use [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/511443-cross-platform-startfile-and-mailto-functions/) python recipe for a portable and sound way to send mails with attachments in python.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. With `python t.py -m a@g.com --attach="file://home/aha/top.png"` a client (thunderbird) is opening but without a file as attachment. mailto_string in line 286 is: `mailto:a@g.com?attach=file%3A%2F%2Fhome%2Faha%2Ftop.png` what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same result by calling thunderbird via system commands.

Here is a thread that I started. I got a good reply:

[Python: Open Thunderbird to write new mail with attached file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25698821/python-open-thunderbird-to-write-new-mail-with-attached-file/25705516#25705516)