# Python: Open Thunderbird to write new mail with attached file

Tags: python, email, cross-platform, email-attachments, thunderbird

I would like to open Thunderbird on Debian AND Windows with an attached file for a new email.

So I would like to do the same as in this thread but the posted solution does not work:

[Python open email client with attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25460652/python-open-email-client-with-attachment)

I have the very same problem as user2686223. The file will not be attached to the mail. Can anyone help me with this?

Maybe with another solution?

EDIT: This is now how it works:

```
import os
os.system("thunderbird -compose to='test@test.de',subject='subject',body='body',attachment='/path/to/file'")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start Thunderbird with the command line argument "-compose".
More about it at http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments_%28Thunderbird%29

Answer (score 3):

Using the information from mozillazine listed above, I was able to get this to work with Python 2.7 on Windows 7

```
import subprocess
tbirdPath = r'c:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe'
to = 'recipiant@example.com'
subject = 'Hello'
body = '<html><body><h1>Header</h1>This is the body<br></body></html>'
composeCommand = 'format=html,to={},subject={},body={}'.format(to, subject, body)
subprocess.Popen([tbirdPath, '-compose', composeCommand])
```